# Determine the numbers of solutions of equations $\sin v= \frac{v}{1964}$ and $\sin v= \log_{100} v$ .

Tags: proof-verification, trigonometry, logarithms, contest-math, graphing-functions

***Problem.*** *Determine the number of solutions of each following equation*

- $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$
- $\sin v= \log_{100} v$

***Remark.*** *This problem is similar to another one in Moscow Olympiad 1941.*

- *Remark:* $v= 0$ is a solution of $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$. If $v_{0}$ is a solution of $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ then $-v_{0}$ is.
  So we just need to determine the number of positive solutions of $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$. We have $$v= 1964. \sin v\leqq 1964$$
  Therefore, the maximium solution of $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ is not over $1964$. We devide ${\rm Ox}$ (also is ${\rm Ov}$) into $312$ ranges of $2\,\pi$ length and a range of $1964- 312.\,2\,\pi> \pi$ length. Based on the nature of 2 function graphs $y= \sin x= \sin v$ and $y= \dfrac{x}{1964}= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ in $(0, 1964)$, we can determine the number of solutions of $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ as follows
- The first range $(0, 2\,\pi)$, then $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ has only a positive solution.
- All the next ranges (except the final range), $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ has two positive solutions.
- The final range $(312.\,2\,\pi, 1964)$, because this range has a larger length than $\pi$, so it 'contains' enough the part of the graph $y= \sin v$ on ${\rm OX}$, therefore, $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ also has two positive solutions. In conclusion, the number of solutions of $\sin v= \dfrac{v}{1964}$ is $1+ 311.\,2+ 2= 625$ .
- The equation $\sin v= \log_{100} v$ is harder to me because I have not studied $\log$ yet. The condition is $x> 0$ and we have $\log_{100} v\leqq 1$. I think we should devide ${\rm Ox}$ (also is ${\rm Ov}$) into many ranges as *a.*

Comment: The no. of solutions to the first problem is $626$ not $625$ in the first quadrant. You will subtract one occurence of $v = 0$ only when you double the number of the solutions to include the negative ones also. So, total number of solutions are $626 \mul 2 - 1 = 1521$. You can even check this on desmos.

Comment: I'll notice that, thank you a real lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint on # 2:

$\log_{100} v
=\dfrac{\log(v)}{\log(100)}
$
so
$\log(v) \le \log(100)$
so
$v \le 100
$.

You then have to
divide this into intervals.